# Is it possible to change the order of the tabs shown in the Dictionary?

Tags: macos, dictionary

In my Mac Mini running OS X 10.8, the tabs shown from Dictionary are the following:

- All
- American English
- American English Thesaurus
- Apple
- British English Thesaurus
- Wikipedia
- British English

I would like to change their order, as follows:

- All
- American English
- American English Thesaurus
- British English
- British English Thesaurus
- Apple
- Wikipedia

I tried dragging them, but nothing happens; I also tried selecting them pressing the control keys, but all I got was a contextual menu that allows me to edit the labels, which  is not what I want to do.

Is there any way to change the order that labels are shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just go to the Preferences for the Dictionary app.  There's a list there of all the possible dictionaries, which you can then drag to be in any order you like.

[image]